# When creating a print server, all printer names are invalid

Tags: c#, printing

I'm attempting to create a `PrintServer` using the following code

```
    PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer(@"\\PrinterName");
    PrintQueueCollection printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues();

    foreach(PrintQueue pq in printQueues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pq.Name);
    }
```

but it seems that whatever I put in throws the following exception:

> System.Printing.PrintServerException: 'An exception occurred while
>   creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: The printer name is
>   invalid.'

It may be that I'm putting in the wrong printer name every time, but having tried every possible combination of path I can think of for a few different printers and having the same issue each time I've run out of things to try for this.

I tried following the enabling the Print and Document service as per the [advice shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959842/exception-occurred-while-creating-the-printserver-object-win32-error-the-print) but it hasn't yet helped.

Comment: You do have permissions on that PrinterName server? Are you testing this from a console app?

Comment: @rene yes, I am testing it from a console app. I'm not sure if I have permissions, I can print from that printer but I'm not too clear beyond that